# How to disable Gutenberg / block editor for certain post types?

Tags: php, wordpress, rich-text-editor, wordpress-gutenberg, wp-editor

WordPress added **Gutenberg / block editor** in its 5th version and it's enabled by default for Post and Page post types.

It might be enabled by default for all custom post types in close future so as a WordPress developer I want to know how to disable this editor for my own custom post types? I want to keep classic editor for the post types that I registered from my plugins or themes.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's possible to simply disable the editor using a WordPress filter.

### WordPress 5 and Higher

If you want to disable the block editor only for your own post types, you can add following code into your plugin or `functions.php` file of your theme.

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2);
function prefix_disable_gutenberg($current_status, $post_type)
{
    // Use your post type key instead of 'product'
    if ($post_type === 'product') return false;
    return $current_status;
}
```

If you want to disable the block editor completely (Not recommended), you can use following code.

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false');
```

### Gutenberg Plugin (Before WordPress 5)

If you want to disable the Gutenberg editor only for your own post types, you can add following code into your plugin or `functions.php` file of your theme.

```
add_filter('gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2);
function prefix_disable_gutenberg($current_status, $post_type)
{
    // Use your post type key instead of 'product'
    if ($post_type === 'product') return false;
    return $current_status;
}
```

If you want to disable the Gutenberg editor completely (Not recommended), you can use following code.

```
add_filter('gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', '__return_false');
```

Comment: This filter was renamed to `use_block_editor_for_post_type`.

Comment: The filter must have the variables count (in my case, without it, I have error 500). It works with this: `add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2)`

Comment: for some reason for me the `post_type` parameter value is `'post'` instead of the proper id (or handler) name of the specific cpt post type. Now 2 out of 3 of my cpt types having this issue. (i wiped out all my custom functions, so none of those are generating this issue). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

as the other users shown above it is possible yes. Also, i'd like to make the following known.

In the latest Wordpress or Wordpress  5+ - (With Gutenberg) The 2 methods have the same effect to removing Gutenberg but also have different options when doing so:

(Insert both to functions.php or custom plugin functions)

To remove Gutenberg from your post type:

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2);

 function prefix_disable_gutenberg($gutenberg_filter, $post_type)
  {
   if ($post_type === 'your_post_type') return false;
   return $gutenberg_filter;
  }
```

The above will remove Gutenberg editor completely from your custom post type but also leave other meta boxes/etc available and untouched.

However, if you wish to remove the text editor/text area itself - or other default options WordPress also considers this as Gutenberg, so you can remove this specifically and remove Gutenberg at the same time by adding the following:

```
add_action('init', 'init_remove_editor',100);

 function init_remove_editor(){
  $post_type = 'your_post_type';
  remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor');
 }
```

The above will disable Gutenberg & the 'editor' of wordpress. This can replaced with other metabox/data options. (Author / Thumbnail /Revisions etc)

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you use **custom post type**.

When you register a cpt add `add_post_type_support( 'news', 'excerpt' );`

Full example :

```
function create_news() {
    $args = [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => __( 'News', 'lang' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'News', 'lang' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add a news', 'lang' ),
    ],
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-post',
        'show_in_rest' => false,
        'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'news'],
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    ];

    register_post_type( 'news',
        $args
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_news' );
add_post_type_support( 'news', 'excerpt' );
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's a custom post type you can make argument `'show_in_rest' => false,`
and post type will have classic editor

```
register_post_type('test', [
    'label'  => null,
    'labels' => [
        'name'              => 'Test',
        'singular_name'     => 'Test',
        'add_new'           => 'Add test',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add test',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit test',
        'new_item'          => 'New test',
        'view_item'         => 'Watch test',
        'search_items'      => 'Search test',
        'not_found'         => 'Not found',
    ],
    'description'       => 'Post for Test',
    'public'            => true,
    'has_archive'       => false,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-megaphone',
    'show_in_rest'      => false,
    'supports'          => ['title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'],
]);
```

like this

Comment: I personally don't like this solution- it does work however it also disables the CPT from showing in REST API.

Answer (score 0):

To disable specific block on certain post types on WordPress, you can follow this approach that I am using, you'll just have to replace the array values and the custom post type condition.

```
<?php
function disable_specific_blocks( $allowed_block_types, $post ) {
    // An array of block names to disable
    $disabled_blocks = array(
        'core/table',
        'core/image',
        'core/gallery',
    );
  
    // Use this condition to disable blocks on certain post types, otherwise you can remove this IF condition
    if ( $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
        $allowed_block_types = array_diff( $allowed_block_types, $disabled_blocks );
    }

    return $allowed_block_types;
}
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'disable_specific_blocks', 10, 2 );
?>
```

You can also check this full tutorial on [how to disable specific Gutenberg blocks](https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-disable-specific-blocks-in-the-wordpress-gutenberg-block-editor/).

Answer (score -1):

If you like to remove editor or any other field from your custom post type then use this code in functions.php file

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'custom post name', 'filed name' );
}, 99);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you **register the custom post types** in your plugin, the quickest solution to disable the block editor is by setting the option [`show_in_rest`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#show_in_rest) to false in [`register_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/):

```php
<?php
$args = array(
  'label'        => 'Custom Posts',
  'show_ui'      => true,
  'show_in_rest' => false,          // ← Disables the block editor.
);
register_post_type( 'my-cpt-slug', $args );
```