# wpbakery does not work and giving me a blank white screen with wpbakery logo

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wpbakery

i'm using wpbakery plugin to build web pages. Yesterday i found that i wasn’t able to edit any pages or posts. Page builder is giving me a blank white screen with wpbakery logo on every single page or post I try to edit. If I disable page builder then I can not edit  then none of my page builder pages work correctly. What can I do to get page builder working again?

Comment: You may need to update the plugin, or other plugins.  I would start with updating all of your plugins.  Do one by one, to see if the issue resolves.

Comment: i did that but still did not work

Comment: Try deleting the plugin and re-installing it.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a problem of a **compatibility issue** between the WP Bakery live editor and new WordPress Guttenberg editor.
To solve the problem you can:

1 - Add this snippet in your code.

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', false, 10);
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', false, 10);
```

2 - Install [Classic editor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) via your WordPress Dashboard.

Comment: This almost works. I can see part of the page now, but still the logo and white screen is on top of the page. Is there another wordpress filter that can be used to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe you´re working with custom post types. Then you can visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199629/how-to-disable-gutenberg-block-editor-for-certain-post-types and check filter.